# Hide/Remove an extra dropdown widget from jQuery ColumnFIlterWidget plugin in Angular Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

Basically I am trying to achieve 2 things here. I am using columnFilterWidget.js jQuery DataTable Plugin here for column filtering. I am having some issues in "Excluding" one Extra dropdown which is the 6th `<td>` and it has entire dataTable content HTML. Currently Excluding 6th Column is taking off all data and is showing an empty datatable

Here is my HTML:

```
<table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions"
    dt-instance="dtInstanceCallback" style="width: 100%" id="quoteMgmt">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Origin City</th>
            <th>Origin State</th>
            <th>Destination City</th>
            <th>Destination State</th>
            <th></th> 

       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr ng-repeat="quote in mgmtQuote track by quote.quoteNumber">

            <td style="display: none">
                {{ quote.customerInfoVo.customerName }}</td>
            <td style="display: none">
                {{ quote.eqmCommonInfo.origCity }}</td>
            <td style="display: none">
                {{ quote.eqmCommonInfo.origState }}</td>
            <td style="display: none">
                {{ quote.eqmCommonInfo.destCity }}</td>
            <td style="display: none">
                {{ quote.eqmCommonInfo.destState }}</td>    

            <td>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="seven columns">
                    [Datatable Content]
```

Here is my app.js

```
 $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
                .withOption('sDom', 'ltip')
                .withOption('iDisplayLength', 25)
                .withOption('fnDrawCallback',function(oSettings){$(oSettings.nTHead).hide();SpinnerService.hide();})
                .withOption('aaSorting',[])
                .withLanguage({"sEmptyTable":"No quotes available"})
                .withOption("sDom", 'W<"clear">lfrtip')
                .withOption('aoColumnDefs',[{
                    'bVisible':true,'aTargets':[0,1,2,3,4]
                }])
                .withOption('aoColumnDefs',[{
                    'bVisible':false,'aTargets':[5]
                }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix it by using the syntax differently. On using Angular Datatable DTOptionsBuilder, syntaxes should be used little carefully. Posting my answer in case if it helps someone.

```
   $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
                .withOption('iDisplayLength', 25)
                .withOption('fnDrawCallback',function(oSettings){$(oSettings.nTHead).hide();SpinnerService.hide();})
                .withOption('aaSorting',[])
                .withOption('bJQueryUI',false)
                .withOption('bDeferRender',true)
                .withLanguage({"sEmptyTable":"No quotes available"})
                .withOption("sPaginationType",'full_numbers')
                .withOption('sDom', 'W<"clear">lrtip')
                .withOption("aoColumns",[
                   /*0 Customer */         {"bVisible":false},
                   /*1 Origin City */      {"bVisible":false},
                   /*2 Origin State */     {"bVisible":false},
                   /*3 Desination City */  {"bVisible":false},
                   /*4 Desination State */ {"bVisible":false},
                   /*5 Equipment Type */   {"bVisible":false},
                   /*6 Entire Datatable */ {"bVisible":true},
                   /*7 Sent Date */        {"bVisible":false},
                   /*8 Expiration Date */  {"bVisible":false},
                   /*9 Awarded Date */     {"bVisible":false},
                   /*10 Awarded Date desc*/{"bVisible":false}
                 ])
                 .withOption("oColumnFilterWidgets",{
                      "aiExclude":[6,7,8,9,10],
                      "sSeparator": "\\s*/+\\s*",
                      "bGroupTerms": false,
                 })
```